# How to hide scrollbar on small media devices while still allowing scrolling?

Tags: google-chrome, sass, scroll

I have searched for similar posts but have not found a working solution.

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar on smaller screen devices while still allowing the user to scroll left to right.

Here is my current styling:

```
    @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 320px;
      display: -webkit-box !important;
      display: -moz-box !important;
      -webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

Setting the display to none will actually make the scrollable area disappear.

Comment: Hi @ghostagent151 - does this help - https://blog.hubspot.com/website/hide-scrollbar-css?

Comment: @MrR Thanks that helped

Comment: Hi @ghostagent151 - why don't you post your solution as an answer?